# how to avoid Memory leaks when using Generics.add<TClass.Create(AParams)>

Tags: delphi, generics, memory-leaks

i have this example here:

```
    uses
  System.Generics.Collections;

type
  TMouseDrag = class
    FX, FY: Integer;
    constructor Create(AX, AY: Integer);
  end;

  TFrmMain = class(TForm)
    Btn_FillList: TButton;
    LV_MouseDrag: TListView;
    procedure Btn_FillListClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  FrmMain: TFrmMain;
  List_MouseDrag: TList<TMouseDrag>;
  AItems: TListItem;
  FMouseMove: Integer;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TMouseDrag }

constructor TMouseDrag.Create(AX, AY: Integer);
begin
  FX := AX; FY := AY;
//  Free;
end;
{ TFrmMain }
procedure TFrmMain.Btn_FillListClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  List_MouseDrag.Add(TMouseDrag.Create(Random(100), Random(100)));

  LV_MouseDrag.Items.BeginUpdate;
    AItems := LV_MouseDrag.Items.Add;
    AItems.Caption := List_MouseDrag.Items[FMouseMove].FX.ToString;
    AItems.SubItems.Add(List_MouseDrag.Items[FMouseMove].FY.ToString);
    inc(FMouseMove);
  LV_MouseDrag.Items.EndUpdate;
end;

initialization
  FMouseMove := 0;
  List_MouseDrag := TList<TMouseDrag>.Create;

finalization
  List_MouseDrag.Free;
```

for ex: when i click button three times i got a memory leaks says[13-20 bytes: TMouseDrag x3]
and when i activate the `free` methode inside `TMouseDrag` Create bloc is ok but this will clear `List_MouseDrag` Values ...
Do I missing something?
why `List_MouseDrag` can't free Also `TMouseDrag` Items when its Free?

Comment: Use `TObjectList<T>` instead. And you cannot call `Free` in the ctor. And you should use fields instead of global variables, use `try..finally` to protect the `BeginUpdate`, etc.

Comment: Another option would be to declare `TMouseDrag` as record. Using class seems like overkill here.  If this is just simplified example and you really need a class, then use `TObjectList<TMouseDrag>` like @AndreasRejbrand suggested.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH ALL